# Windows - can I alias a local folder to a "spoofed" non-existent UNC name?

Tags: windows, mklink, unc

I am troubleshooting code that runs on a customer's network.  I have all the data files and configuration files from the customer and am setting about trying to reproduce the issue.  The problem is the customer's configuration files are littered with references to `\\SomeComputer\SomeName\AFolder` and it would be really helpful if I could map `\\SomeComputer\SomeName\` to a local folder on my development machine so that I could re-create the customer environment with as little effort as possible.

What I want is some way I can refer to `d:\AFolder` with `\\SomeComputer\SomeName\AFolder`, in much the same way as I can have `mklink /D C:\SomeName\AFolder D:\AFolder`.

I need to clarify with some more sensibly-named entities:

Lets assume that the software I am troubleshooting references the file `\\Customer1Computer\Customer1Share\Reports\Report.pdf` and the reference is hard-coded.  I create the local folders:

```
D:\Jobs\Customer1\Customer1PC\ 
D:\Jobs\Customer1\Customer1PC\Reports\
```

I want any references to `\\Customer1Computer\Customer1Share\` in the application to go to `D:\Jobs\Customer1\Customer1PC\`

Comment: you can always create aliases for those systems using DNS CNAME records, or the hosts file if you don't have a DNS server. create a share for d:\AFolder, and then create the alias. you should be able to access it using \\somecomputer\someshare. https://www.howtogeek.com/784196/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-windows-10-or-11/

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I would need to accomplish this via the `hosts` file. I have added a bit of clarification to the question in the form of an example.  Using those names and working through your comments:  I have created a folder `D:\Jobs\Customer1\Customer1PC\Reports\ `.  I have created a share called `Customer1PC` pointing to `D:\Jobs\Customer1\Customer1PC\ `.  I'm unsure where to go from here.  I need to add a line `127.0.0.1  <something> ` to the `hosts` file?

Comment: yep, `127.0.0.1     Customer1PC`.  once you have the alias in the file (a reboot may be needed), you can test it using `net view Customer1PC` or putting `\\customer1pc\customer1share` into the address bar in explorer. you may need to adjust permissions on the shared directory, based on user in question, and what the program needs to do. Note, the name `Customer1Computer` is too long. Windows system names cannot exceed 15 characters. use `Customer1PC` instead.

Comment: OK, added alias line to `hosts`, rebooted. Now I can't see any network computers under `Network` although I can type `\\MyPC` into explorer address bar and see that PC's shares.  `MyPC` doesn't appear in the list of network PCs though.  Nothing does. If I type `\\Customer1PC` into explorer I get a credentials dialog, but no account/password combinations work.   `net view Customer1PC` gives access denied.  I also found this: https://nolongerset.com/unc-alias-for-a-local-folder/ which suggests it isn't possible using the `hosts` file.  It also mentions the authentication problem.

Comment: OK Update:  `MyPC` has shown up under `Network`.  I can now `dir \\MyPC\Customer1PC`, but \\Customer1PC still access denied.

Comment: try using the system ip in the host file instead of 127.0.0.1.  I've always used a DNS server for this, so I suppose its possible that it won't work. does the code authenticate with a particular user account?

Comment: By system IP you mean the IP address of the PC I want to create the spoof share on right? - in this case 192.168.178.99.  Same result I'm afraid.  The application doesn't do any authentication (and I'm not at that stage yet anyway, I'm still trying to make `\\Customer1PC` exist).

Answer (score 0):

By default a Windows SMB Server only allows inbound connections to IP addresses and hostnames of the SMB server. Here is the proper way to setup a hostname alias for an SMB file server

https://4sysops.com/archives/disable-strict-name-checking-with-powershell/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.